# Modifying text in resetZoomButton doesn't work - highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I have been trying to modify the text for `resetZoomButton` using the theme option as follows:
http://jsfiddle.net/xurXt/

However, the new text seems to take effect only when I hover over the zoom button.

What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 4):

In the lang object you can set default [resetZoom](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#lang.resetZoom) text.

Comment: It will change it for all the charts. I want to do it for a specific chart.